# define an event for custom android toast

Tags: android-toast

I've made a custom android toast and tried to define on click listener event for the textview, but it doesn't work....any help??

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(cntxt);

```
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,null);


    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);

    text.setText(msg);

Toast toast = new Toast(cntxt);

    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setView(layout);

    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method s'tub 
                //didn't go here???
                toast.cancel();
            }
        });

    toast.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a `Toast` and any child child views of a `Toast` cannot receive touch input. You will have to create a custom `View` that mimics a `Toast` and attach that `View` to a layout.